# Kafka consumer failed record needs to be stored in file and needs to be re processed

Tags: spring-boot, apache-kafka

I have a KafkaConsumer which consumes messages, does some processing and then a KafkaProducer sends message to another topic. I am currently manually committing the offset using `Acknowledge.acknowledge()` when KafkaProducer successfully sends message to another topic, but I do not call Acknowledge.acknowledge() when message fails to send. I have `set ackMode to AckMode.MANUAL_IMMEDIATE`

However when I do not commit the offset manually, KafkaConsumer should pick the same record that failed to process (i.e failed to send to another topic) but even on failure the offset is incremented and the next record is processed. Can anyone tell me why this is happening? And how can I achieve this by process the failed records, business people mentioned like don't want create the kafka topic/DB for store the error records and reprocess it. Ihave only option to store the error data in file only for store, reprocess and publish to the destination kafka topic. Could some one help me to resolve this issue?

Comment: What's preventing you from writing an exception handler that writes to a file?

Comment: We can write into the file whenever we are getting the error in destination part failure but the challege is we need to proccess the record whatever we storing in the file.  Do we need write one more listener for read this file and publish it into destination, is this right approach?

Comment: Assuming your records are plaintext, just store them on individual lines. I don't know what you mean by "write a listener" since you don't "listen to files", you just open a `BufferedReader`to read their content

Comment: Can you share your contact whatsapp number?

Comment: Let me explain what I'm expecting? This one Banking related project, need to have some extra attention for read the file and publish it into kakfa topic

Comment: Then read the file into a list of ProducerRecords. That's also not that complicated.

Comment: After written into the file we can read on by one and publish it for failure record. We need to avoid the duplicate read from the file. If we trying to publish the failuee record again its getting failed how to again read the file. If it's happening repeatedly, how we can handle the error records?

Comment: Use a database rather than a file and mark which records have been processed successfully

Comment: Unfortunately we cannot use the database. It's might be completed with files. Could you please help me?

Comment: You need some other system that's able to track progress, then, so make more than one file... For example, use a sqlite database, which is really just a file itself. I'm not able to "help" you write this because I really don't think it's possible to do what you want

Comment: Im ususing asynchronous that's the only challenge